# why the schedule not working automatically

Tags: laravel, scheduled-tasks

I try to send a notification to the users of a course 1 hour prior to starting exam so, I made command which send notification, the problem is when I run php artisan schedule:work in cmd the notification will saved in the database and schedule works but when I expect it run automatically noting saved in the database.
thanks in advance

kernel.php

```
     protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
     
       $schedule->command('users:notify')->everyMinute();
    }
```

NotifyUsers.php

```
class NotifyUsers extends Command
{
         protected $signature = 'users:notify';
         protected $description = 'notify to users';

public function handle(){
         $quizzes = Quiz::whereDate('start_date', now()->addHour())->get();
         $students = [];
         $titles = [];
              foreach($quizzes as $quiz){
                 $students = $quiz->course->users;
                     $title = $quiz->title;
                     array_push($titles, $title );
                  }
                  foreach($titles as $title){
                     foreach($students as $student){
                          Notification::send($student, new timeToExam($title));
                  }
             }
        
    }
```

timeToExam.php  // notification

```
class timeToExam extends Notification
                         {
        use Queueable;

         public $title;

    
public function __construct($title)
{
    $this->title = $title;
}

public function via($notifiable)
{
   return ['database'];
}

  
public function toArray($notifiable)
{
    return [
          'title' => $this->title,
        ];
}
```

Comment: using linux or windows ? on your live if you have cpanel you can use `cronjob` from it.

Comment: use windows on local not server

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set a cron job on your windows machine.
[This link](https://blog.codehunger.in/cron-job-in-laravel-8-setting-up-cron-in-windows-pc) may help you find your solution.